# Spring Data Mongo with Koltin coroutines and @DocumentReference

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data MongoDB with Kotlin Coroutines to create a non-blocking server.
I have a document `Deck`:

```
@Document 
data class Deck(
@Id val id: ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),
@DocumentReference(lazy = true) val author: User,
val title: String,
val desc: String,
@DocumentReference(lazy = true) val cards : Set<Card> = emptySet(),
@CreatedDate val createdAt: Instant = Instant.now(),
@LastModifiedDate val lastModifiedAt: Instant = Instant.now()
)
```

`Deck` has a reference to a `User` type in the author field:

```
@Document
data class User(
@Id val id: ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),
val name: String,
@Indexed(unique = true, name = "username_index") val username: String,
val password: String,
@CreatedDate val createdAt: Instant = Instant.now(),
@LastModifiedDate val lastModifiedAt: Instant = Instant.now(),
@DocumentReference(lazy = true) val decks: Set<Deck> = emptySet()
)
```

Here's my `DeckRepository` interface:

```
interface DeckRepository: CoroutineSortingRepository<Deck, String> {
}
```

The `Deck` documents are getting saved properly in the database with the author's `ObjectId`.
But when I try to fetch the deck with id, the repository method gives an error. It's not able to populate the author's reference.

```
override suspend fun getDeck(deckId: String): DeckResponseDTO {
    log.info("Getting deck with id $deckId")
    return deckRepository.findById(deckId)?.toDto() ?: throw Exception("Could not find deck with id $deckId")
    }
```

Stacktrace snippets:

```
Failed to instantiate io.gitub.startswithzed.dex.model.Deck using constructor fun <init>(org.bson.types.ObjectId, io.gitub.startswithzed.dex.model.User, kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.collections.Set<io.gitub.startswithzed.dex.model.Card>, java.time.Instant, java.time.Instant): io.gitub.startswithzed.dex.model.Deck with arguments 63173407712ec0263535829a,null,Test title,Test Desc,null,2022-09-06T11:50:31.370Z,2022-09-06T11:50:31.370Z,16,null
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$DefaultingKotlinClassInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:215) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method io.gitub.startswithzed.dex.model.Deck.<init>, parameter author
at io.gitub.startswithzed.dex.model.Deck.<init>(Deck.kt) ~[main/:na]
at io.gitub.startswithzed.dex.model.Deck.<init>(Deck.kt:14) ~[main/:na]
```

I even verified the data by querying using lookup in the console. Somehow Spring Data is not able to query properly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you would like to save, the id should be null because Spring will run insert or update depending on id is null or not. Another think, use this: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoId annotation

Comment: Another: ID type is ObjectId then you need: `CoroutineSortingRepository<Deck, ObjectId>`

Comment: I have worked with MongoDB repositories in this manner before without facing any problem. Only difference is that now i'm using coroutines. Nevertheless I made the changes and gave it a try but got the exact same result. The issue is not in finding the deck object. It's successfully able to fetch it. It's not able to populate the user  from the @DocumentReference.

Comment: Can you upload an example code onto GitHub? To test this code on my environment?